# Removing special filenames from the filesystem on Windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer

How is it possible to remove a three-dotted directory on Windows 7, such as "... "?

I have acquired this directory via a FTP session from an unix-like OS.

I have attempted the removal with 'command prompt', as well as forcibly trying to rename the directory in Windows Explorer or moving it to the recycler - all of it resulted in failure or explorer crash, as "... " is, apparently, expanded to "... "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you delete it if you specify the whole path?  I.e.:

```
del c:\full\path\to\stupid\file\...
```

Another option might be to delete the directory that contains the stupid file (possibly after moving any important files somewhere else).

In other words, create a new directory, `C:\full\path\to\stupid\file2`, then copy everything (except the stupid ... file) from `C:\full\path\to\stupid\file` to `C:\full\path\to\stupid\file2`, then delete `C:\full\path\to\stupid\file`, and rename the new directory back to the original name.

Comment: trying to directly remove the troubled filename did not yield any positive outcome. the filename is perceived as a 'special' directory by Windows Explorer. once clicked - this is the resulting path: "C:\RECYCLER\a\...\...". so, basically, it turns into a double "..." :). i have tried `rd /S /Q` before, in a parent directory (with a target of "...") and vice versa. now, however, i have tried to do the same but by specifying the full path and targeting the root directory of "..." - that worked out successfully. the solution is to use the full path and aim for the root directory;good hint, thanks